# How to rotate TickLabels in DateListPlot

Tags: plotting, ticks, rotation

I tried to rotate my `TickLabels` with another contribution from this website.

I load the package CustomTicks.m

```
Beta0 = Import["beta0_Monatsende.xls"];
DateListPlot[Beta0, PlotRange -> Full; 
FrameLabel -> {Zeit [Monat], Subscript[\[Beta], 0]}, 
FrameTicks -> {{LinTicks[0, 14, 2, 2], 
 LinTicks[0, 14, 2, 
  2]}, {{{1972, 09}, {1975, 09}, {1978, 09}, {1981, 09}, {1984, 
   09}, {1987, 09}}, Automatic}}, 
DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthNameShort", " ", "Year"}] /.x : (FrameTicks -> _) :> (x /. s_String :> Rotate[s, 90 Degree])
```

Now the labels on the `x` axis are rotated, but also on the `y` axis. Is there any possibility to rotate only the labels on the x axis?

[image]

Comment: Where did `LinTicks[]` come from?

Comment: I load the package CustomTicks.m

Comment: Yes, please mention if you have loaded any packages that are not built-in in your question the next time.

Comment: sorry, i edit my contribution

Comment: After the `/.` in the snippet you gave, try this replacement rule instead: `x : (FrameTicks -> _) :> MapAt[# /. s_String :> Rotate[s, π/2] &, x, {2, 2, 1}]`

Comment: It works! Wow, thank you!

Comment: (If anyone else wants to write it up as an answer, please do so; my *gedanken Mathematica* does not allow for producing plots.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom ticks function:

```
rotatedDateTicksF[n_]:= MapAt[Rotate[#, Pi/2] &, System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[{##}, 
   n, {"MonthNameShort", " ", "Year"}], {All, 2}] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
data = Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 2}, 20]];
DateListPlot[data, {{2015, 1, 1}, Automatic, "Month"}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {rotatedDateTicksF[5], Automatic}}, 
  FrameLabel -> {Zeit[Monat], Subscript[β, 0]}, 
  DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthNameShort", " ", "Year"}]
```

[image]

Change `rotatedDateTicksF[5]` to `rotatedDateTicksF[10]` to get

[image]

Comment: I tried it with version 12.0.0.0. It did not worked (anymore?): "A ticks specification in the value of FrameTicks should be None, Automatic, a function, or a list of ticks"

Comment: or does it not work because I need the package above??

Comment: @M.A., I don't understand why it doesn't work in v12.0. A work-around is to use `rotatedDateTicksF[5][{2015, 1, 1}, DatePlus[{2015, 1, 1}, {20, "Month"}]]` instead of  `rotatedDateTicksF[5]` (You don't need the `CustomTicks` package for this)