# Combine BarChart and TimeLinePlot

Tags: plotting, date-and-time, charts

I have a Barchart like this:

```
data = {{1995, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3}, {1996, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3}, {1997, 0.5, 0.1,
     0.4}, {1998, 0.6, 0.1, 0.3}, {1999, 0.9, 0, 0.1}, {2000, 0.5, 
    0.2, 0.3}, {2001, 0.5, 0.5, 0}, {2002, 0.5, 0.5, 0}, {2003, 0.5, 
    0.5, 0}, {2004, 0.3, 0.7, 0}, {2005, 0.1, 0.9, 0}};
BarChart[data[[All, 2 ;; 4]], ChartLayout -> "Percentile", 
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
 PlotRange -> {{All, All}, {All, All}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 0.3}, {0, 0}}, 
 PlotLabel -> Style["Label", Black, 18], 
 FrameLabel -> {None, Style["relative share [%]", 14]}, 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[IntegerPart[data[[All, 1]]], Axis, 
    Rotate[#, Pi/2] &], None}, ChartLegends -> {"1", "2", "3"}, 
 ChartStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}, BarSpacing -> {0, 1}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", 12}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", 12}, ImageSize -> {700, 400}]
```

Now I have some events which occur in specific years like in this timeline:

```
timeline = 
TimelinePlot[{Labeled[DateObject[{1998}], "Event A"], 
  Labeled[DateObject[{2001}], "Event B"], 
  Labeled[DateObject[{2005}], "Event C"]}]
```

Now I want to combine theses two plots so that the timeline is under the barchart but it should be well aligned (years in the same position and the callouts below the time axis). Is there a way to do this? Or maybe there is a better solution instead of `TimeLinePlot`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. To use [`DateHistogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateHistogram.html) instead of `BarChart` (so that the chart and the timeline plot share a common date axis) we construct a list of [`WeightedData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedData.html) objects:

```
wd = WeightedData[data[[All, {1}]], data[[All, #]]] & /@ {2, 3, 4};
```

2. To use  the graphics primitives produced by `TimelinePlot` as `Epilog` in `DateHistogram` we need to modify the vertical scales and positions of primitives. The function `translateScale` does this job.

```
ClearAll[translateScale]
translateScale[t_: - .07, s_: .05] := GeometricTransformation[#, 
   TranslationTransform[{0, t}] @* ScalingTransform[{1, s}]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
timeline = TimelinePlot[{Labeled[DateObject[{1998, 7, 15}], "Event A"], 
    Labeled[DateObject[{2001, 7, 15}], "Event B"], 
    Labeled[DateObject[{2005, 7, 15}], "Event C"]}, 
   AxesOrigin -> Top, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"];

dh = DateHistogram[wd, "Year", ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 ChartStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, ImageSize -> Large,
 Ticks -> {AbsoluteTime /@ Thread[{data[[All, 1]], 7, 15}], Automatic}, 
 DateTicksFormat -> {"Year"}, 
 ChartBaseStyle -> Opacity[1], PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, 50}, {120, 10}}, 
 Epilog -> translateScale[][First @ timeline]]
```

[image]

Add the option `PlotLayout -> "Grouped"` in `timeline` and re-evaluate `dh` to get:

[image]

Post-process `dh` to add spacing between groups:

```
dh /. RectangleBox[{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}, e_] :> 
  RectangleBox[{a + (c - a)/6, b}, {c - (c - a)/6, d}, e]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> 11.3 .0 for Microsoft Windows (64 - bit) (March 7, 2018)

**Note:** In Version 12.0, change `RectangleBox` to `Rectangle` in the replacement rule for modifying spacings.

**Update:** To rotate date labels, you can use

```
Ticks -> {{#, Rotate[DateString[#, "Year"], 90 Degree]} & /@ 
   AbsoluteTime /@ Thread[{data[[All, 1]], 7, 15}], Automatic}
```

and `Epilog -> translateScale[-.1][First @ timeline]` to get

[image]

Comment: that is brilliant, thx! However, after replicating your code, the last row (add spacing between the bars) does not seem to work...

Comment: @M.A., can you post a small example where the replacement rule to change spacings doesn't work?

Comment: @M.A., it could be version/OS-related. I am using version 11.3 (windows 10-64bit).

Comment: @M.A., just tried the same example in v12.0 (wolfram cloud). It seems that the only change needed is to replace `RectangleBox` with `Rectangle`.

Comment: I tried to combine insights form this post here (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183528/how-to-rotate-ticklabels-in-datelistplot/183534?noredirect=1#comment547344_183534) in order to rotate the ticks. It works but the years are not centered in the middle of the bars but on left side. any idea?

Comment: @M.A., maybe you can post the label alignment issue as a question (cannot think of a quick solution off the top of my head)