# Rotate Ticks in a Histogram

Tags: graphics, labeling, histograms, ticks, charts

I have a histogram like the one presented here by @kglr
 ([Combine BarChart and TimeLinePlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198558/combine-barchart-and-timelineplot/213678?noredirect=1#213678)). For the sake of brevity, I excluded the issue with `timelineplot`:

```
(*some data preprocessing:*)

data = {{2000, 2, 0, 6, 4}, {2001, 0, 0, 8, 14}, {2002, 1, 0, 10, 
    13}, {2003, 4, 0, 8, 9}, {2004, 3, 0, 13, 11}, {2005, 0, 1, 9, 
    7}, {2006, 3, 2, 2, 8}, {2007, 0, 0, 11, 7}, {2008, 6, 1, 8, 
    8}, {2009, 2, 5, 2, 7}, {2010, 4, 2, 11, 14}, {2011, 4, 0, 5, 
    11}, {2012, 6, 2, 11, 10}, {2013, 5, 0, 8, 11}, {2014, 1, 3, 10, 
    7}, {2015, 0, 0, 9, 6}};
makeshares[{year_, amb_, neg_, neu_, pos_}] := 
  Module[{total, shares}, total = Total[{amb, neg, neu, pos}]; 
   shares = {year, pos/total // N, neu/total // N, amb/total // N, 
     neg/total // N}];
data2 = makeshares[#] & /@ data;
data2shares = 
  WeightedData[data2[[All, {1}]], data2[[All, #]]] & /@ {2, 3, 4, 5};
```

The histogram

```
data2histogramm = 
 DateHistogram[data2shares, "Year", ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
  ChartStyle -> {Opacity[0.9, Darker[Blue]], Opacity[0.7, Pink], 
    Opacity[0.7, Orange], Opacity[0.9, Darker[Yellow]]}, 
  ImageSize -> {700, 500}, 
  Ticks -> {AbsoluteTime /@ 
     Thread[{tradeevaluationsdata2[[All, 1]], 7, 15}], Automatic}, 
  Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
  DateTicksFormat -> {"Year"}, ChartBaseStyle -> Opacity[1], 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
  ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, 50}, {140, 10}}]
```

yields

[image]

Now, inspired by a custom ticks function presented here: [How to rotate TickLabels in DateListPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183528/how-to-rotate-ticklabels-in-datelistplot), I tried to rotate the ticks:

```
rotatedDateTicksF[n_] := 
  MapAt[Rotate[#, Pi/2] &, 
    System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[{##}, n, {"Year"}], {All, 2}] &;
```

the new histogram

```
data2histogramm2 = 
 DateHistogram[data2shares, "Year", ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
  ChartStyle -> {Opacity[0.9, Darker[Blue]], Opacity[0.7, Pink], 
    Opacity[0.7, Orange], Opacity[0.9, Darker[Yellow]]}, 
  ImageSize -> {700, 500}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
     Automatic}, {rotatedDateTicksF[15][{2000}, 
      DatePlus[{2000}, {15, "Year"}]], Automatic}}, 
  Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
  ChartBaseStyle -> Opacity[1], PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
  ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, 50}, {120, 10}}]
```

yields:[image]

Unfortunately, the ticks are on the left edge below each bar, so how can I put them into the middle (below the bar)?

Comment: Ticks functionality needs an update soon!

Comment: @M.R. Yes, I sure hope they give it some TLC soon. It's easily my highest friction interaction with Mathematica, though perhaps this is not so for others. CustomTicks usually does everything I need, but it's a pain when collaborating or working in the Cloud.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic},
 {MapAt[DatePlus[#, {6, "Month"}] &, 
    rotatedDateTicksF[15][{2000}, DatePlus[{2000}, {15, "Year"}]], {All, 1}], 
  Automatic}}
```

to get

[image]